# Can't parse JSON data from api in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to get this working but I don't now why it isnt working out.

```js
//require the poloniex library
var plnx;
var currenciesJSON;
if (plnx = require('plnx')){
  console.log("Poloniex library intialized.");
}
//

a = 0;
setInterval(function() { intervalFunction() }, 1000);


function intervalFunction(){

  plnx.returnCurrencies({}, function(err, data) {
    currenciesJSON = data;
    console.log(err);
    console.log(currenciesJSON);

  });

  var currenciesOBJ = JSON.parse(currenciesJSON);

  a++;
  console.log("Check #"+a+" complete.");
}
```

I'm getting the follow errors:

```
[nodemon] starting `node main.js`
Poloniex library intialized.
undefined:1
undefined
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

at Object.parse (native)
at intervalFunction (E:\CODING\nodejs\main.js:22:28)
at null.<anonymous> (E:\CODING\nodejs\main.js:10:26)
at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:265:14)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: The Json you received is valid? Get the result console.log(currenciesJSON) and put in www.jsonlint.com to validate

Comment: It seems like your ``currenciesJSON`` contains invalid JSON string.

Comment: currenciesJSON is likely undefined because its value is being set inside an async callback.  put your `currenciesObj = JSON.parse(currenciesJSON);a++;console.log(...)` inside the callback.

Comment: Have you also verified that `typeof data === 'string'` inside your callback? It could very well be that it's already an object, and thus does not need parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse the value of a variable before it is assigned. `plnx.returnCurrencies()` is async and so

```
var currenciesOBJ = JSON.parse(currenciesJSON)
```

will be (initially) equivalent to

```
var currenciesOBJ = JSON.parse(undefined)
```

which will be equivalent to (due to type coercion)

```
var currenciesOBJ = JSON.parse('undefined')
```

hence the SyntaxError error about the character `'u'`

This is only likely to be a problem until the `plnx.returnCurrencies()` callback is called at least once, since then the `currenciesJSON` will be defined.